# extracting text from <b> tags in html using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

This is the portion of html code that express the information that I want to extract from a webpage. My intention is to extract just the names and values between the b tags. The result I expect is a list something like this: `[On,DVI,396,2035,2551]`

```
 ...   
<div class="txt"><br> 
Power: <b>On</b><br><br>
Source: <b>DVI</b><br><br>
Lamp runtime: <b>396</b> hours<br>
Lamp remaining: <b>2035</b> hours<br>
Total operation: <b>2551</b> hours<br>
</div>
...
```

What I tried was:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url='ip address here'
html=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
main_div=soup.find("div",{"class":"txt"})
data=main_div.findAll('b').text
```

What did go wrong? FYI, I am a beginner so please bear with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
data=[b.string for b in main_div.findAll('b')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

```
import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div class="txt"><br> 
\nPower: <b>On</b><br><br>
\nSource: <b>DVI</b><br><br>
\nLamp runtime: <b>396</b> hours<br>
\nLamp remaining: <b>2035</b> hours<br>
\nTotal operation: <b>2551</b> hours<br>
\n</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
bTags = [] 

for i in soup.findAll('b'):
    bTags.append(i.text)
```

Contents of bTags:

```
[u'On', u'DVI', u'396', u'2035', u'2551']
```

Comment: i just want the text inside b tags within this particular div tab with class called txt.. there are other div tabs with b tabs in my html..so if i find all the b tags in the html file like in your code, there will be a lot of btags . But thanks for the help .. this is another way of doing it if there is only 1 div tag.